# gorm has many relation with foreignKey reference

Tags: go, go-gorm, go-gin

My goal is to archive a "has many" relation with gorm

I don't want to have any generated IDs so I intentionally did not use gorm.Model in my structs

I set up my two structs like:

```
type Application struct {
  Name         string        `json:"name" gorm:"primaryKey"`
  Description  string        `json:"description"`
  Translations []Translation `json:"titles" gorm:"foreignKey:ApplicationName;references:Name"`
}

type Translation struct {
  ApplicationName string `json:"applicationName" gorm:"primaryKey"`
  Locale          string `json:"locale" gorm:"primaryKey"`
  Value           string `json:"value"`
}
```

Translation.ApplicationName should be the foreignKey to Applications

(Translation.ApplicationName + Translation.Locale) the primary key for Translations

After creating an application

```
{
  "name" : "postedApplication1",
  "description" : "postedDescription3",
  "titles" : [
    {
        "locale": "de-DE",
        "value":"deutsch"
    },
     {
        "locale": "de-AT",
        "value":"AT"
    }
  ]
}
```

I got following error

> ON CONFLICT clause does not match any PRIMARY KEY or UNIQUE constraint
> [0.065ms] [rows:0] INSERT INTO `translations`
> (`application_name`,`locale`,`value`) VALUES
> ("postedApplication1","de-DE","deutsch"),("postedApplication1","de-AT","AT")
> ON CONFLICT (`application_name`,`locale`) DO UPDATE SET
> `application_name`=`excluded`.`application_name`

and

> ON CONFLICT clause does not match any PRIMARY KEY or UNIQUE constraint
> [0.531ms] [rows:0] UPDATE `applications` SET
> `description`="postedDescription3" WHERE `name` = "postedApplication1"
> [GIN] 2021/08/27 - 11:23:00 | 200 |     841.953µs |       127.0.0.1 |
> POST     "/applications"

Someone any idea what I'm doing wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED  qx.X,p

Everything was correct!

After I installed vscode-sqlite and inspected the database I just recognized that the sqlite tables were not like I designed them

The problem was that AutoMigrate which produced an invalid state due changing a lot during developing

```
database.AutoMigrate(&models.Application{}, &models.Translation{})
```

I had to delete sqlite "gorm.db" file and restart the application